# Locked Classes with VBA/VB

Tags: vba, class

I want to package my classes (in VBA or VB), but I want to put a lock on them before I do so. I want the computer to return a message similar to one in the Word file attached. Can anybody point me in the right direction? There doesn’t seem to be a lot of help in this regard.

I would need something that would lock just the classes that I have made while still leaving the rest. My understanding is that the mde would compile the whole works, and therefore would not work. Is that correct?

Could you have 2 projects for 1 mdb file? Then I could allow 1 project to be locked (mine) and then the other to be open to everyone

Marty Habicht

Answer (score 0):

An add-in may suit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa902693.aspx

You can create an mde and include it as a refernce in other Access applications (code window, Tools-References).

Answer (score 0):

See my [Add-in Tips, Hints and Gotchas](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/addins.htm) page for an Access only answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to put the classes in an mde, and then just set a reference to the MDE from the unlocked project. This will give you access to the class, while rendering your source unviewable. This won't stop a determined reverser, but I don't really think a determined reverser is in the threat model:)